# Python activity

Tags: windows, python

I am attempting to use a program in Geany which is designed to tell me whether a number is even or odd. Here is the program I have written.

```
def activity01(num1):
    '''Determine if an input number is Even or Odd'''
    if [num1 % 2 == 0]
        return 'even'
    else: 
        return 'odd'
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this program? It is telling me right now that line 3 has invalid syntax at the end. I am running the program in a test environment from the class I got the activity through.

Comment: There's a colon missing from the end of your `if` statement. Also, the square brackets will cause the `if` statement to be always true (square brackets mean a list, and a list is truthy if it contains at least one element, such as the result of your expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a colon after `if (num1 % 2 == 0)`. You should be able to use the code below for your function:

```
def activity01(num1):
   """Determine if an input number is Even or Odd"""
   if num1 % 2 == 0:
      return "even"
   else:
      return "odd"

print activity01(3)
print activity01(4)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried with the colon before but I think something else was wrong when I did that! This is my second day of python (which is my first computer programing language), thanks for helping me out!